# unsupported operand types for python classes

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to make a mock pokemon game, but every time it throws the error "unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'int' and 'move'" for this code:

```
class pokemon(object):

    def __init__(self,hp):
        self.hp = hp

    def getHit(self,damage,hp):
        self.hp -= damage
        print str(self.hp)

class move(object):
    def __init__(self,damage):
        self.damage = damage


unit = pokemon(10)
tackle = move(3)
enemyUnit = pokemon(4)
enemyUnit.getHit(tackle,unit)
```

what do I need to change to make my code work?

Comment: Still looking at your code but just as an aside, with python code it makes things lots easier for others if you stick with the generally accepted convention of starting your class names with upper case so they don't look like functions

Comment: possible duplicate of [unsupported operand for 3 instances of two classes and one method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874948/unsupported-operand-for-3-instances-of-two-classes-and-one-method)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to pass a property of the class, not the class itself.

```
enemyUnit.getHit(tackle.damage,unit)
```

Comment: +1 Lol I forgot you could return the attribute `damage` itself :)

Comment: I tried your fix, and it worked, so thanks, but if I want to add another property, like an attack stat taken from unit to multiply with the damage, it won't let me just put
        enemyUnit.getHit(tackle.damage,unit.attack)
without it saying getHit takes 4 arguments and I've only put 3...

Answer (score 1):

with `enemyUnit.getHit(tackle,unit)` your passing pokemon objects while your `getHit` method is expecting numbers