# unsupported operand for 3 instances of two classes and one method?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to get the program to take the hp stat from `enemyUnit`, the attack stat from `unit`, and the damage stat from `tackle` and put them into one math problem in the method `getHit()`.  this is the code:

```
class Pokemon(object):    
    def __init__(self,hp,attack,defence):
        self.hp = hp
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence
    def getHit(self,damage,hp,attack):
        self.hp -= damage * self.attack/self.defence
        print str(self.hp)

class Move(object):
    def __init__(self,damage):
        self.damage = damage


unit = Pokemon(10,2,3)
enemyUnit = Pokemon(4,2,3)
tackle = Move(3)


enemyUnit.getHit(enemyUnit,tackle,unit)
```

unfortunately it gives me the error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Pokemon' and 'int'
```

how do I get it to take all the variables from all instances of each class and put them into one function?

Comment: You don't use `hp` or `attack` and are passing a `Pokemon` and treating it as a number.

Answer (score 1):

In the `getHit()` method you are passing the arguments:

- `hp`
- `attack`
- `defence`

but when you call it in `enemyUnit.getHit(enemyUnit, tackle, unit)` you are passing `enemyUnit` which is an object of the `Pokemon` class. This causes the error.

You may want to pass the correct parameters in:

```
enemyUnit.getHit(...) # Correct the parameters
```

**Edit:**

I think the best idea would be to implement the `getHit()` method like this:

```
def getHit(self, other, move): 
    self.hp -= move.damage * other.attack / self.defence
    print str(self.hp)
```

and call it with:

```
enemyUnit.getHit(unit, tackle)
```

Note that you were passing `hp` and `attack`, which are attributes of `Pokemon`. You can use them by just calling `obj.hp` and `obj.attack`.

Comment: ok, so how do I pass it all the variables from all the objects? as in, what are the correct parameters?

Comment: See edit please, you may want to redefine the `getHit()` method